# Как передать значение из одного input в другой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью `onchange` у `<input type="number" id="1" value="100">` передавать его значение для `<input type="hidden" id="2" value="">`?

Пробовал так:

```js
        document.querySelector('#1').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            function snd(1, 2) {
                document.getElementById(2).value = document.getElementById(2).value;
            }
        })
```

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Это не учебный вопрос. Код добавил.

Comment: зачем функция в функции? onchange != submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="number" id="1" value="100">

<input type="text" id="2" value="">

<script>

    document.getElementById('1').addEventListener('change', function(e){
        document.getElementById('2').value = e.target.value;
    })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Странно. Выдает ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Подправил код, я ошибся. Попробуйте теперь